# Pattern matching, Why I got unexpected result?

Tags: elixir

I have `rows` equals to `[%{a: 0, b: 10}, %{a: 1, b: 11}]`

if I do:

```
 Enum.map(rows, fn %{a: value} -> value end)
```

I get:

```
[0, 1]
```

But, if I do:

```
Enum.map(rows, fn %{b: value} -> value end)
```

I get unexpected result:

```
'\n\v'
```

but not the expected result: `[10, 11]`

Any idea?